# what is the effect of assign a variable to itself in PHP?

Tags: php, variable-assignment

I was studying a piece of code from [HTTP-Tunnel Project](http://http-tunnel.sourceforge.net/) which i faced with this wired variable assignment in line 315 in file lib.php

```
if ($publicname) $sysn=$sysn=$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]?$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]:$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
```

i can't understand why variable $sysn has been assign to itself?

the function which the line of code is in it:

```
function getmyip ($publicname) {
// try to get the name wih multiple methods in this order:
// $publicname: SERVER_ADDR, SERVER_NAME, php_uname, uname, hostname, own script
// !$publicname: php_uname, uname, hostname, own script, SERVER_ADDR, SERVER_NAME,
$sysn="";
if ($publicname) $sysn=$sysn=$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]?$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]:$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
if (!$sysn || $sysn=="127.0.0.1" || $sysn=="localhost" || preg_match("/\s/",$sysn)) $sysn=php_uname("n");
if (!$sysn || $sysn=="127.0.0.1" || $sysn=="localhost" || preg_match("/\s/",$sysn)) $sysn=`uname -n`;
if (!$sysn || $sysn=="127.0.0.1" || $sysn=="localhost" || preg_match("/\s/",$sysn)) $sysn=`hostname`;
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]!="127.0.0.1" && $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]!="locahost") {
    $sysurl="http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?a=ip";
    $sysn=file_get_contents($sysurl);
    $sysn=preg_replace("/\\r|\\n/","",$sysn);
}
if (!$sysn || $sysn=="127.0.0.1" || $sysn=="localhost" || preg_match("/\s/",$sysn))
    $sysn=$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]?$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]:$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
if (!$sysn) $sysn=$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
return gethostbyname($sysn);
}
```

Comment: im guessing typo, as it does nothing

Comment: That looks strange to me, but I do notice that the assignment is actually the conditional statement of a ternary statement.  I can't decipher this myself either, but I think that is a good frame of reference to start with.

Comment: I'd call that a ternary statement too. I guess that second equals sign should have been a double one, so `==` insteadof `=`...

Comment: @arkascha i don't thinks so because the type of $sysn variable is String and it has been confirm by gethostbyname($sysn);

Comment: @smith i thinks so,  but could it be variable shadow?

Comment: @EhsanGhasemlou ... which makes perfect sense to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is awful code, and you shouldn't use it, but it's essentially a poorly-written NULL coalesce. A NULL coalesce boils down to:

```
if( is_null($bar) ) {
    $foo = 'some default or alternate value';
} else {
    $foo = $bar;
}
```

For better readability:

```
$sysn = (
    ($sysn = $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]) ?
         $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] :
         $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] 
);
```

Note that evaluating the result of an assignment operation returns the value that was assigned, and the assignment operations are *right-associative* so they are chained from right to left.

A more succint example:

```
$foo = ( $foo = $bar ) ? $bar : 'bar was unset';
//       ^- NULL, which is false-y
var_dump($foo);

$bar = 'I am bar';
$foo = ( $foo = $bar ) ? $bar : 'bar was unset';
//       ^- string, which is truth-y
var_dump($foo);
```

Output:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: bar in /in/q2A4n on line 1
string(13) "bar was unset"
string(8) "I am bar"
```

Notices should not be ignored, they indicate that you're doing something wrong. Not wrong enough to halt execution, but wrong enough to potentially cause problems somewhere down the line.

If this was written by a person with standards and the ability to feel shame it would be:

```
$sysn = (
    ( isset($_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]) ) ?
         $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] :
         $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] 
);
```

Or in PHP>=7 with the [NULL coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
$sysn = $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] ?? $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]
```

Comment: wow, it was the most perfect answer that i ever seen, thanks a lot.
but please recheck the line 16 in the function implementation code in the question (or 325 in lib.php).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think you're right. `$a = $a = $c ? $d : $e` is equivalent to `$a = ($a = $c) ? $d : $e` by a mere coincidence. `$a = $b = $c ? $d : $e` is actually `$a = ($b = ($c ? $d : $e))` because the ternary operator has a higher precedence than assignment (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Anyways, the second assignment still remains a mystery as it doesn't change the resulting semantics even in this interpretation. Also, while you're right that `isset($a) ? $a : $b` is equivalent to `$a ?? $b`, it is not equivalent to the original `$a ? $a : $b`.

Answer (score 1):

It would do exactly nothing. This would be same as.

```
if ($publicname) $sysn=$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]?$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]:$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
```

maybe a typo? or something?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, the [assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) operator has a right associativity. Meaning, that a variable that is assigned to another variable which is being assigned to something, will just end up with those variables being assigned to the right-most value. Since the variables are the same, the logic does not change is one of the `$synsn` are removed.